# How to control the Total Line of a table in an SSRS Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have created the following SSRS Report format below.  If the item list gets over 3 items I page break on a grouping and the items list continues.

The issue is on the first page I would like to have a summary/total line that says "cont" on any page that is not the last page.  On the last page I would like to show the totals. Any recommendations?

```
QTY     ITEM     PRICE
1       item1     1.21
2       item2     2.25
3       item3     4.56
cont     cont     cont

QTY     ITEM     PRICE
4       item4     1.21
5       item5     2.25
6       item6     4.56
21               16.04
```

Comment: If you managed to get the grouping done correctly , simply use an expression that checks if you're at the end of the datasource.

Comment: Grouping is done correctly.  How do you check the end of a data-source as an expression in SSRS report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the function [`RowNumber("ScopeName")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225.aspx) to calculate the current value's row number, and use this to check if it is the same as the total scope row count, [`CountRows("ScopeName")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156330.aspx).